# .htaccess rule not working correctly (non-www to www redirect)

Tags: .htaccess

Here is format of my URLs: `www.domainname.com/in/laptop.html`

In .htaccess I have set to call `search.php?country=in&source=seo_url&keyword=laptop.html`

**Rule used:**

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
 RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/([\w-]+).html$ search.php?country=$1&source=seo_url&keyword=$2.html
```

**Now issue is** if someone call 
`domainname.com/in/laptop.html` (without www), it does not show any product

Then I used below rule to redirect non-www to www URL

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**What is happening:**
When I call `domainname.com/in/laptop.html` , it redirect to below URL

```
http://www.domainname.com/search.php/laptops.html?country=in&source=seo_url&keyword=laptops.html
```

**What It should do:**
if call `domainname.com/in/laptop.html` , it should redirect to `www.domainname.com/in/laptop.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect to www before rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/([\w-]+).html$ search.php?country=$1&source=seo_url&keyword=$2.html
```